# Prove for a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

So my task is to prove that if $N$ is finite group and *$G$ is a normal subgroup of $N$*
and $(|G| , |N : G|) = 1$ , for every subgroup of N (let's call it F) if $|F|$ divides $|G|$, $F$ is a subgroup of $G$.

So my first approach was with Lagrange's theorem. But I don't know how to use the statement that $(|G| , |N : G|) = 1$. 
Any tips ?

Comment: I suppose that you meant to write that $\lvert F\rvert$ divides $\lvert G\rvert$, instad of $\lvert G\rvert$ divides $\lvert G\rvert$.

Comment: I am almost sure that at least 96% of all mathematics books have : "$G$ is a group and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then..." You changed this and it makes things pretty confusing...and anyway: the condition makes no sense: $|G|$ divides $|G|$ ...?

Comment: |F| divides |G|. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Take $g\in F$ and consider the standard map $\pi\colon N\longrightarrow N/G$. Then the order of $\pi(g)$ diveds both the order of $g$ and the order of $N/G$. But these numbers are coprime. Therefore, the order of $g$ is $1$. In other words, $g\in\ker\pi= G$.